# Looping over list of dicts and removing elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm facing a problem that I don't really understand. Please take a look at the given code, where the two relevant variables have the following form:

```
jsd = {"data": {"User": .....}}
lists = [{"genre": "XY", "meanScore": Float},..., {"genre": "XY", "meanScore": Float}]
```

The code is:

```
jsd = json.loads(r.text)  
lists = jsd["data"]["User"]["stats"]["favouredGenresOverview"]
for k, entry in enumerate(lists):
    if entry["meanScore"] == None:
        del(lists[k])
```

The goal is to remove all the `dict`'s in `lists` where the key `meanScore` is equal to `None`. The problem is that for some reason the loop only runs over half of `lists`... I think I've read somewhere on the site that when trying to remove something from a `dict` one should use `pop`, but I honestly wasn't able to figure out how to that or if it even was relevant to my question (As far as I understand I'm removing list elements).

Can someone maybe help?

Comment: Don't delete items from a list while iterating; plenty of duplicates for the strange behaviour but I think that one best illustrates the skipping of elements. Build a new list of things you want to _keep_ rather than delete elements.

Comment: don't modify (the shape of) what you're iterating through!

Comment: @ParitoshSingh don't modify the _length_ of what you are iterating through. Maybe I have a list of integers and I want to multiply them all by 2; I wouldn't have this issue.

Comment: Touche. Not quite as catchy though. :P

Comment: Instead of removing unwanted items from the original list, add wanted items to a new list. As others have said, don't iterate and remove from a collection at the same time, if you do so you desserve all kinds of nasty things, and you're getting them. If you need na explanation of why and what is happening, let me know.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues that is already covered fully in the duplicate I have flagged

Comment: @roganjosh Yep, stackoverflow was outdated on my side. Thumbs up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more pythonic approach to these type of problems is to think of what you want to "keep" instead.

```
jsd = json.loads(r.text)  
lists = jsd["data"]["User"]["stats"]["favouredGenresOverview"]

output_list = [entry for entry in lists if entry["meanScore"] is not None]
```

You can get fancier with a generator and slicing if you want to do it inplace.

```
lists[:] = (entry for entry in lists if entry["meanScore"] is not None)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lists = [{"genre": "XY", "meanScore": 'Float'}, {"genre": "XY", "meanScore": None}]
[d for d in lists if d['meanScore'] is not None]
```

This will give the following output

```
[{'meanScore': None, 'genre': 'XY'}]
```

Comment: Though `None` is falsy, so if much else! To include only `None`, an explicit `if d['meanScore'] is not None` is needed.

Comment: Heads up though, that condition would falsify empty strings/0/empty lists and so on.

Comment: @jmd_dk You're correct. I'll fix that.